# AWS Managed Grafana w/SSO - How to stay logged in for kiosk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, grafana

I'm testing out AWS Managed Grafana w/SSO and everything works well enough, except auth is subject to AWS' normal session timeouts, which makes it annoying to use in kiosk mode.

Is there any way to make it *not* timeout a session? So I don't need to log in every day?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user with View only access resolved this for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding that it would be great to get more information about your solution Nabeel. I am also facing the same problem as the original poster, and I'm a bit stumped on how to solve it.